# JavaScript calling function 4 times but I need to execute function only one time

Tags: javascript, react-native, algorithm, callback

I have listener when any change in volume execute callback function 4 times
callback call other function
I need that function execute only one
what is the best way

when lisiner detect any change callback call recognitionCameraBySoundVolum() 4 time

```
volumeListener = SystemSetting.addVolumeListener((data) => { 
    recognitionCameraBySoundVolum();
});
```

need to excute this function only once instead of 4

```
   const recognisionCameraBySoundVolum = () => {
        console.log("hi from recognitionCameraBySoundVolum "); 
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to remove the listener then it will add multiple listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the useEffect hook?

It should look something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    volumeListener = SystemSetting.addVolumeListener((data) => { 
        recognitionCameraBySoundVolum();
    });

    // return remove listener method in the cleanup section 
}, []);
```

Comment: I ask general not this specific case
I Solved problem by add flag and control execution by it

Answer (score 0):

this worked with me

```
useEffect(() => {
const volumeListener = SystemSetting.addVolumeListener( (data) => { 
    const volume = data.value;  

}); 
return () => 
SystemSetting.removeVolumeListener(volumeListener)  
}, [])
```